# Clang Apple C++11 correct setup for CMake

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, cmake, clang

I am trying to configure CMake to compile for OS X Target.This is IMac with OS X Yosemite v 10.10.2

Clang version:

Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)

Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0

When I compile without putting any compiler flags I am getting one error for this chunk of code in one the sources:

```
 static const char* LogLevelStr[] {
     "TRACE  " ,
     "INFO   " ,
     "WARNING" ,
     "ERROR  " ,
     "FATAL  " ,
};
```

> error: definition of variable with array type needs an
>         explicit size or an initializer

I am compiling this code on Windows and GCC and it is completely fine so I don't understand why Clang complains here.So I decided,maybe I have to set C++11 support flags because I use this standard in the code a lot.

Setting

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

or

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -std=c++11")
```

Adds even more  weird errors like these:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__bit_reference:51:52:
>   error: 
>         expected ';' at end of declaration list
>       _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY operator bool() const _NOEXCEPT
>                                                      ^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__bit_reference:87:57:
>   error: 
>         expected ';' at end of declaration swap(__bit_reference<_Cp> __x, __bit_reference<_Cp> __y) _NOEXCEPT
>                                                           ^ >/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolc>hain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__bit_reference:87:58:
>   error: 
>         C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations >swap(__bit_reference<_Cp> __x, __bit_reference<_Cp> __y) _NOEXCEPT
>                                                            ^ >/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__config:338:21:
>   note: 
>         expanded from macro '_NOEXCEPT'
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__bit_reference:89:10:
>   error: 
>         expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
>       bool __t = __x;
>       ~~~~ ^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__bit_reference:92:2:
>   error: 
>         expected ';' after top level declarator }  ^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__bit_reference:1111:47:
>   error: 
>         expected ';' at end of declaration list
>       _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY __bit_iterator() _NOEXCEPT

The error block from above the compiler spits at the point it is trying to parse  include

Now,I tried also to set:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++")
```

Same errors.

What do I miss here?

UPDATE:

I don't understand why some people marked this question for closing.Anyway,here is the problem in more details.I tried all those C++11 flags.I also added '=' to that static array.But most of the errors come after that.And it looks like root of those is  .At the very first place where  gets parsed it goes down into another class called __bit_reference and there at line 51 the compiler complains
on the following line 
 _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY operator bool() const _NOEXCEPT

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__bit_reference:51:52:
>   Expected ';' at end of declaration list

Most of the other errors are also in some ways connected to stl containers.

So my question is still valid.How do I get my source code to compile with the latest Clang on OS X including C++11 support.I am trying  to do that with Xcode and have the same issues.

Xcode compiler output(some of it):

> CompileC
>   /Users/michaeliv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxxTest-hdkkzwyyppywsjgmoyuphranqtok/Build/Intermediates/xxxxxxTest.build/Debug/xxxxxxTest.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/XXXMath.o
>   /Users/XXXXXXX/Documents/XXXXX/xxxxxx/src/XXXMath.cpp normal x86_64
>   c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>       cd /Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/xxxxTest
>       export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -x c++ -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu++11 -stdlib=libc++ ....

Comment: Could you post a full log of error messages please?

Comment: I can\t put a full log as I have there also names and paths to  stuff which I can't disclose.I will add more error messages above,But most of them are the same

Comment: Full compiler command-line please.

Comment: In that case, rename any identifiers in the log that are a confidentiality issue.  No log and command line ---> No chance of an answer

Comment: My terminal doesn't show the full command-line of the compiler

Comment: You could also post a [http://sscce.org]

Comment: Really? Perhaps you should read the `cmake` documentation and learn how to turn on verbose output.

Comment: running make VERBOSE=1 doesn't show compiler options as well.

Comment: This is from a clion-created project.  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11") . Maybe CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS gets overwritten?

Comment: @kometen when I set this ,I still have all those errors.Though the explicit array size error is gone.But the rest of them are intact.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say for sure since you aren't posting a reproducible problem.

However, the code sample you posted contains a flaw:

```
static const char* LogLevelStr[] {
     "TRACE  " ,
     "INFO   " ,
     "WARNING" ,
     "ERROR  " ,
     "FATAL  " ,
};
```

should be changed to

```
static const char* LogLevelStr[] = {
     "TRACE  " ,
     "INFO   " ,
     "WARNING" ,
     "ERROR  " ,
     "FATAL  " ,
};
```

I'm not 100% on this as regards the C++11 standard, however, this is my understanding.

When you write `static const char* foo[] = { "foo", "bar", "baz", };` this is aggregate initialization and not list initialization or any other kind. In your code sample, it looks like you are trying to initialize an array using C++11 list-initialization. However, to my knowledge this is not possible, and the "brace-or-equal" syntax described in chapter 8 of the standard does not apply.

This answer refers to "clause 8" to argue that list-initialization of C-style arrays is not permitted by the standard: [Initializing a member array in constructor initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057948/initializing-a-member-array-in-constructor-initializer)

IMO that is the problem and if I were you I would use an `=` there, even if it would be allowed to omit it in C++11 or some future standard.