# initializing a fixed C array member struct

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, multidimensional-array

I have a very simple POD struct containing an array member shown below. I am having problems initializing the fixed length array member `memberArray` with a reference fixed length array parameter `const uint32_t(&rArrayArg)[22]`. I will not have access to the standard library in the final target environment.

The member initializer `memberArray{*rArrayArg}` only copies the first entry from the `rArrayArg` arg.  In order to see the complete array, I need to memcpy or (as shown here) std::copy in the body of the constructor.

I have another POD struct that takes a 2 dimensional fixed length array `const uint32_t(&rArrayArg)[4][5]` which will be used to initialize a corresponding 2d member, so a general solution for the member initialization syntax would be preferred.

```
struct TestStruct {
    explicit TestStruct(
        const uint32_t(&rArrayArg)[22])
        : memberArray{*rArrayArg}
    {
        //std::copy(std::cbegin(rArrayArg), std::cend(rArrayArg), memberArray);
    }

    uint32_t memberArray[22];

    // this stream helper is only present for debugging purposes
    // in the actual target environment, I will not have access to std:: 
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const TestStruct& rhs) {
        os << "TestStruct: ";
        for (auto next : rhs.memberArray) {
            os << next << ",";
        }
        return os;
    }
};
```

The following [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb1c1a12dc3b7321) shows the result of passing a partially populated fixed array parameter `uint32_t fixedLenArg[22] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};` to the explicit constructor.  Printing the results shows:

```
TestStruct: 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
```

so clearly only the first parameter is being copied.  If I uncomment the std::copy in the body of the constructor (this is debug as I do not have access to std::copy in the final environment) I get the following:

```
TestStruct: 1,2,3,4,5,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
```

Comment: So to be clear you can neither `std::copy` nor `std::memcpy`? If that's the case might need to roll your own, either copy in a for loop or implement your own copy method

Comment: @CoryKramer Actually I will have access to memcpy but my real question is how to avoid that or use it in the member initialization (as opposed to in the body of the constructor)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057948/initializing-a-member-array-in-constructor-initializer) answer your question?

Comment: @CoryKramer +1 for getting close but its not quite what I need, I need to be able to pass in an lvalue of a fixed array type reference - I thought that there was some syntax where this array could be copied in its entirety via some syntax trick I am unaware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I understood the problem correctly, then this should work:

```
struct TestStruct {
  constexpr static size_t arraySize = 22;

  explicit TestStruct(const uint32_t(&rArrayArg)[arraySize]) : memberArray() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i)
        memberArray[i] = rArrayArg[i];
  }

  uint32_t memberArray[arraySize];

  // this stream helper is only present for debugging purposes
  // in the actual target environment, I will not have access to std::
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const TestStruct& rhs) {
    os << "TestStruct: ";
    for (auto next : rhs.memberArray) {
      os << next << ",";
    }
    return os;
  }
};
```

Comment: Great. While you are at it, I'd also recommend ditching the sizeof trick in favor of a `static constexpr std::size_t n = 22;`

Comment: This also generalizes straightforward to the 2D case. If code reuse is a concern, it could also be extracted easily into a function. +1

Answer (score 2):

If you're allowed to use `std::array`, this becomes pretty trivial:

```
struct TestStruct { 
    explicit TestStruct(std::array<uint32_t, 22> const& rArrayArg)
        : memberArray{rArrayArg}
    {}

    std::array<uint32_t, 22> memberArray;

    // this stream helper is only present for debugging purposes
    // in the actual target environment, I will not have access to std:: 
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const TestStruct& rhs) {
        os << "TestStruct: ";
        for (auto next : rhs.memberArray) {
            os << next << ",";
        }
        return os;
    }
};
```

The built-in copy constructor for `std::array` will do all the work that needs to take place.

Comment: Please read my question, no STL 'I will not have access to the standard library in the final target environment.'

Comment: @johnco3 You shouldn't tag the question as C++11 then, as having that implies access to the STL.

Comment: @Xirema - A freestanding implementation need not have most of the standard library available. And it's perfectly valid C++11