# Is it possible to set a specific member of an array with initialization list in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I know that you can initialize the whole array with initialization list like this :

```
struct s {
    int a[1];
    s (int b): a{b}{}
};
```

, but is it possible to set value of one specific member? Because this:

```
struct s {
    int a[1];
    s (int b): a[0]{}
};
```

doesn't work and throws two errors:

> ```
> expected '(' before '[' token
> ```

and

> ```
> expected '{' before '[' token.
> ```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4057948/5470596

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize an element of an array by placing the value in the appropriate position via [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

```
struct s {
    int a[2];
    s (int b): a{b, 0} {} // sets a[0] with the value of b
                          // a[1] is set to zero
};

s foo(1);  
std::cout << foo.a[0] << " " << foo.a[1]; // 1 0
```

**UPDATE** (thanks @NathanOliver)

Missing elements are [zero initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).

```
struct s {
    int a[2];
    s (int b): a{b} {} // a[1] is already 0
};
```

Comment: FWIW `a{b}` will also do the same thing since any missing element is zero initialized.

Comment: @NathanOliver, thank you. updated to capture this important information.

Answer (score 1):

No. Only [initializing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers) the specialized elements of an array is supported in C, but not C++.

> Note: ..., and designated initialization of arrays are all supported in the C programming language, but are not allowed in C++.
>
> ```
> int arr[3] = {[1] = 5};        // valid C, invalid C++ (array)
> ```

You can use assignment as workaround.

```
struct s {
    int a[1];
    s (int b) { a[0] = b; }
};
```