# How to initialize array members from initialization list in C++03?

Tags: c++, initializer-list, c++03

The following works fine in C++11, but doesn't work in C++03.

```
struct Foo {
    int a, b;
    Foo(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}
};

struct Bar {
    Foo foos[2];
    Bar(int i) :
        foos{ {i + 1, i + 2}, {i + 2, i + 3} },
    {}
};

int main() {}
```

What could be a C++03 workaround?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4057948/2612235) is quite similar, but it doesn't really address the same usecase. Here I would like to build the subclass from `Bar` arguments.

Comment: The mentionned question doesn't really answer this one. It doesn't provide any C03++ example.

Comment: @Jason I'm almost certain the question you linked does not provide a workaround for when `Foo` has no default constructor (it's about an `int` array instead). It just says it's not valid syntax.

Comment: @Nelfeal That is what I mean, that it is not possible in c++03 to "initialize" as op wants. You can do "assignment" though in c++03.

Comment: @Jason But OP specifically asks for a workaround... Doing assignments here is not a workaround since you still can't default-initialize `foos`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Foo` has no default constructor, you cannot initialize a `Foo` array without C++11's [list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

Your first option is to use a version of C++ that isn't two decades old, but I suppose that's not an option for you, otherwise you would not be asking this.

There are a few other options, but none of them (as far as I know) allow you to keep the array intact.

### Use dynamic allocation

```
struct BarNew {
    Foo* foos;
    BarNew(int i) : foos(static_cast<Foo*>(::operator new(sizeof(Foo) * 2)))
    {
        new (foos + 0) Foo(i+1, i+2);
        new (foos + 1) Foo(i+2, i+3);
    }
};
```

This can look complicated because you cannot use `new` directly without calling the constructor, and that's not possible for an array (again, only prior to C++11). Calling `::operator new` allocates without initializing, just like `malloc` does in C. You then need to use placement-new to actually construct each object.

### Use `std::vector`

```
struct BarVector {
    std::vector<Foo> foos;
    BarVector(int i)
    {
        foos.reserve(2);
        foos.push_back(Foo(i+1, i+2));
        foos.push_back(Foo(i+2, i+3));
    }
};
```

This is the simplest option, with the main drawback being that is also uses dynamic allocation, unlike an array. The call to `reserve` is of course optional.

### Use an array wrapper

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct ArrayWrapper {
    union {
        char buffer[sizeof(T)];
        unsigned long long dummy;
    } storage[N];

    T& operator[](std::size_t i) {
        return reinterpret_cast<T&>(storage[i]);
    }
};

struct BarStruct {
private:
    static ArrayWrapper<Foo, 2> foos_init(int i) {
        ArrayWrapper<Foo, 2> foos;
        foos[0] = Foo(i+1, i+2);
        foos[1] = Foo(i+2, i+3);
        return foos;
    }

public:
    ArrayWrapper<Foo, 2> foos;
    BarStruct(int i) : foos(foos_init(i))
    {
    }
};
```

This is the most complicated of these three options, but it has the advantage of not using dynamic allocation. It can be made to behave much like a simple array.
The `ArrayWrapper` struct here is generic, so you can use it for types other than `Foo`. It contains a buffer (array of `char`) to contain each `Foo` object, and uses a union for alignment purposes, because [`alignas`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) is, again, a C++11 addition. I'm not 100% confident it works in every case; I think you have to pray that `unsigned long long` has a good enough alignment. If `sizeof(T) < sizeof(unsigned long long)`, you will be wasting some space, but you could write a template specialization if that worries you.
`foos_init` exists only to provide the initialization values. After the constructor, you can use `foos` like an array.

[See that all three options compile in C++03.](https://godbolt.org/z/jsdKobo6Y)

There is yet another option I can think of, but I'm not confident enough that it would work or in my abilities to write it, so I'm leaving it as an idea. It's a combination of options 2 and 3, where you would provide a storage on the stack just like `ArrayWrapper::storage`, but then use it for a `std::vector` thanks to the "allocator" feature (the second template argument of `std::vector`). That way, you get all the fancy methods of a `std::vector` without allocating anything on the heap.